# mobile all-in-one airco unit evac via unused chimney?

Tags: air-conditioning, heat-pump, hose

We've begun to consider options to install some form of airco in the attic which serves as our bedroom (the higher part; South) and my office (a lower part, North). The piece runs the length of the house, has drywalls, chalet-style wood panelling on the ceiling (and inside of the slanted roof). 2 roof windows, older Velux units of approx. 60cm wide, one on each end. There's an unused attic on the Eastern side, separated by a rather thick stone wall. There's a chimney in the bedroom part, prolongation of a currently unused insert fireplace in the room below.

A monosplit unit would probably be the best solution, installed under the ceiling against the south-eastern wall, but I don't know if the external unit could be placed in the adjected attic, nor how problematic it would be connect the two through the stone wall. The living room and my wife's office are directly underneath, separated by a an old, traditional French ceiling that provides almost no sonic isolation at all, and might not even support a heavy unit. Access to that attic is cumbersome too, so maintenance would be a real chore.

So a "simple" all-in-one mobile unit might be the more practical solution were it not for the fact it requires a 100-150cm diam. tube to be passed outside; not easy with toppling Velux windows. Creating a passage in the wall would be problematic too.

I don't suppose one could insert that tube into the chimney, or can one? There's a trap door in the chimney which we could replace by another door with an appropriate hole during the months airco is required. As I said, the chimney isn't used ATM and it actually has 2 channels.

Thanks in advance for any useful insights!

Comment: You definitely cannot have the condensing of a mini split a/c in an enclosed attic, even if the attic is vented. The condensing unit must be outdoors.

Comment: Interesting, on one of the main, authoritave DIY sites here in France they describe so-called "climatisateurs gainables" as a solution where the central unit can be installed in an attic, for instance to prevent neighbour disturbance. Anyway, it looks like that's a solution that would be too cumbersome anyway, so the most likely one would be something like https://www.leroymerlin.fr/v3/p/produits/climatiseur-mobile-reversible-wood-s-cortina-silent-12k-smarthome-3520-w-e1505979888 - if we can find a solution for the evac tube (hose?).

Comment: FWIW, fixing one of those ugly condensing warts to the front of the house is probably out of the question where we live.

Comment: And BTW the chimney in question should be deep enough (40cm) to make an additional hole in the side, just under the ceiling.

Comment: What about having the condensing unit on the ground? Would it be possible to hide it behind some plants? These have a low noise level, I think. The tubes and wires connecting to the evaporator/air handler are hidden in a covered chase which can be painted to match the wall.

Comment: In the US standard sized split a/c are often installed with the evap unit/air handler in an attic, but the condensing units are always outside.

Comment: Unlikely. We don't own the terrain (asphalt ...) just in front of the house, so the only thing we could have the unit with is one of our cars... And we'd need a horizontal offset as the floor of the entrance room is about 30cm below street level, so there is no space for a condenser under the window and its blinds.